# Are these two methods the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to go from passing a rules option to the $("#" + formName).validate({}) method to using the $.validator.addClassRules({}) method.  Are these the same thing?  The second doesn't work.

current method (works)-

```
var validatorObject = $("#" + formName).validate({

 rules: {
   firstField:{
     equalTo: ['#secondField']
   },
   secondField:{
     equalTo: ['#firstField']
   }
});
```

preferred method (doesn't work) -

```
var myValidator = Validator.addForm("formName");
$.validator.addClassRules({
       firstField:{
         equalTo: ['#secondField']
       },
       secondField:{
         equalTo: ['#firstField']
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are not equivalent. The first defines rules based on the *`name`* of the input element:

> Key is the name of an element (or a
>   group of checkboxes/radio buttons)

[The second](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addClassRules) adds rules that are based on the *`class`* of an element. This is useful when you want multiple elements to share a validation rule.

If you wanted to use the second method, you'd have to add a class `firstField` and `secondField` to the inputs you wanted validated with those rules.